# Screen sharing freezes in Chrome on Mac Air with HTML5 MediaRecorder

Tags: javascript, html, macos, mediarecorder

I have developed an application which records screen, video and audio using HTML5 MediaRecorder. The entire process of recording works without any issues on Windows Machine. But If I access the same web application on Mac Air, I have a strange issue (Refer below scenario)

**Recording without screen freeze**

Open browser > Start recording. Open another application like word or notepad etc. Keep both the screens stacked side by side.

**Recording (screen freeze)**

Open browser > Start recording. Open another application like word or notepad etc. Make sure both applications are displayed in fullscreen mode.

It seems the recording works smoothly when the browser is in foreground. As soon as browser window goes in background and another application window is displayed, the video recording freezes but audio gets recorded.

Is there any configuration/setting that can be applied at Mac/Chrome level to ensure applications running in the background are not suspended from display rendering.

PS: The screen sharing permission dialog also doesn't display all the open windows in "Application Window" tab. It just displays chrome tab.

**Update 1**

The behavior is confirmed after few trials and errors. This is happening due to spaces. Each new application window is getting started in new spaces. Even after turning off the spaces from mission control, there is still a problem. If an application is viewed as full screen, it gets assigned to new display. Same happens with powerpoint presentation mode. Workaround is to make sure that press alt/option key while clicking on maximize button (no fullscreen / no presentation).

Comment: dosen't have Mac :(

Comment: Me too ;( I have asked someone to test the application.